Why does my 2-FSK samples have the max value across the whole band?
I am trying to generate 2-FSK I/Q samples to use with a HackRF. I iterate through the bits like this:
size_t sample_index = 0;
double t;

for (size_t i = 0; i < num_bits; i++) {
    int bit = bit_sequence[i];
    double freq = (bit == 0) ? FREQ_0 : FREQ_1;

    for (size_t j = 0; j < SAMPLES_PER_BIT; j++) {
        t = (double)(sample_index) / SAMPLE_RATE;

        double I = cos(2 * M_PI * freq * t);
        double Q = sin(2 * M_PI * freq * t);

        I_buffer[sample_index] = (int8_t)(I * 127);
        Q_buffer[sample_index] = (int8_t)(Q * 127);

        sample_index++;
    }
}

When I look at the generated samples using Inspectrum, it is maxed out across the whole spectrum.

Am I supposed to skip n number of samples and write all 0s for all the unwanted frequencies?

You are typecasting as an integer and scaling by 127 so you’re storing using the max dynamic range. You’re clipping your data.

Does that mean I should multiply it by a constant amplitude (eg. 0.05) or something to prevent it from clipping, or should I use a different type and then normalize the values into an integer?

Why are you converting to ints? Remove the scaling and store as floats

The HackRF documentation says it uses 8-bit signed quadrature samples. I looked at this project as a reference, and it was using int8_t for the I and Q components.

Also, where are you accounting for sample rate? You need to divide your time variable by the sample rate.

I have now divided by the sample rate and I got the 2-FSK.

@Sasquatch thanks! I'll clean up my comments :)

Answering my own question. I/Q samples may have different types depending on the device it's intended for, for example:

HackRF: int8_t (*.cs8, *.sc8, *.c8)
RTLSDR: uint8_t (*.cu8, *.uc8)

Since I/Q files don't have any headers to indicate the type of samples, tools like Inspectrum rely on the file extension. If the file just has an arbitrary extension like *.bin, it will by default assume float32. This was why the visualization incorrectly appeared like I was clipping my data.
Upon renaming the file with the cs8 extension, I was able to see the generated signal.

